# bash is eating my string

Tags: bash, shell-script, echo

Consider this short program:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARDUINO_SERIAL=arduino-serial/arduino-serial
PORT="/dev/cu.usbmodem1421"

VERS=$($ARDUINO_SERIAL -q -b 9600 -p $PORT -S 'V' -e '\r' -r)
echo --- VERS = $VERS
B="hello${VERS}goodbye"
echo --- B = $B
```

FWIW, `arduino-serial` is a program that sends a string to an external arduino and echoes its response to stdout.

So I would expect this little script to produce:

```
--- VERS = 00.01
--- B = hello00.01goodbye
```

but instead it's producing

```
--- VERS = 00.01
goodbye
```

I don't understand how the prefix string `--- B = hello00.01` is getting "eaten" rather than echoed.

Can someone explain what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: What are these for: `-S 'V' -e '\r' -r`?

Comment: +1 sounds like a carriage return line termination issue

Comment: After `B=...` put `echo "$B" | hexdump -C` for debugging and be amazed.

Comment: @steeldriver (and AlexP): Sure enough, VERS actually equals "00.01\r\n".  So what's the idiomatically correct way to fix this?

Comment: @tomas: FWIW, those are arguments to the arduino-serial command.  See https://github.com/todbot/arduino-serial for the full scoop.

Comment: Well, the usage section says `-e  --eolchar=char         Specify EOL char for reads (default '\n')` - presumably you should choose the default `\n` endings

Comment: @steeldriver: the -e arg tells arduino-serial what char to look for in terminating the line.  In this case, the arduino is terminates its lines with \r\n, so either -e \n or -e \r will work, but in either case, the resulting string has a \r in it, which is causing the trouble.  `tr` can fix that.  If you don't post an answer with that, I will!  :)

Comment: @fearless_fool please go ahead and post your own answer

Answer (score 2):

Full kudos to @steeldriver for suggesting it was a carriage return line termination issue, and a tip of the hat to @AlexP for suggesting `hexdump` as a way to validate the theory.

The issue is that the string returned by arduino-serial had a trailing '\r\n' (aka 0x0d 0x0a), as evidenced by hexdump:

```
echo "$VERS" | hexdump -C
00000000  30 30 2e 30 31 0d 0a                              |00.01..|
```

One possible fix, and the one I chose, is to pipe the results through `tr -c '\r'` to strip out the return character, so the resulting script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARDUINO_SERIAL=arduino-serial/arduino-serial
PORT="/dev/cu.usbmodem1421"

VERS=$($ARDUINO_SERIAL -q -b 9600 -p $PORT -S 'V' -e '\r' -r | tr -d '\r')
echo --- VERS = $VERS
B="hello${VERS}goodbye"
echo --- B = $B
```

which prints as expected:

```
--- VERS = 00.01
--- B = hello00.01goodbye
```